# Notice: Undefined index: comment_author

Tags: php, mysql

I tried many things from StackOverflow regarding this error but with no luck.

I try to show a reply from a comment. The reply comment is shown along with the date and hour when posted but the author who posted the reply is not shown.

The page with error is `comments.php` on the line `$com_name = $row['comment_author'];`

The code is:

```
<?php
    $get_id = $_GET['post_id'];

    $get_com = "select * from comments where post_id='$get_id'";

    $run_com = mysqli_query($con, $get_com);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_com)){

        $com = $row['comment'];
        $com_name = $row['comment_author'];
        $date = $row['date'];

        echo "

            <div id='comment'>
            <h3>$com_name</h3><i>Said</i> on $date
            <p>$com</p>
            </div>
        ";
    }
?>
```

Hope to sort out this error.

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: What are the column names?

Comment: I'll put money on the fact that `comment_author` is not a column name.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you do a `var_dump($row)` there is not `$row['comment_author']` index.

Comment: The columsn are:
1 comment_id  -> int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT  
2 post_id ->  int(11)
3 user_id -> int(11)
4 comment -> text
5 date -> (timestamp)

Comment: What's the name of user table and what are the column name for this user table?

Comment: `comment_author` doesn't seem to be a column name. Are you sure it's not `user_id`?

Comment: I would bet that `comment_author` is in another table and you need to JOIN this table with that other table using `user_id` to get the authors actual name

Comment: The "comment_author" does not exist in any other table. In the reply box should appear my name who maded the repply. And if i put user_id instead of comment_author the error dissapear and instead of the name of who commented appear number 2 (row 2 from my users table where user is inserted )

Comment: Why are you surprised? You can't fetch something from a database that doesn't exist, if you need to fetch it from POST instead then you need to do `echo $_POST['comment_author'];` instead. (Or `echo $_GET['comment_author'];` depending on your form method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are no column with name `comment_author`. But there are field `user_id`. You need to modify you query to below (assume user table  `users` has fields `user_name` and `user_id`)

```
$get_com = "select c.date, c.comment, u.user_name as comment_author 
    from comments c inner join users u on c.user_id = u.user_id 
    where c.post_id='$get_id'";
```

Comment: How to properly make the query for my needs? I mean on the "c", "u."...

The relationship between tables..how to implement in the code?

I'm sure that what i write is wrong:

$get_com = "select date, comment, user_name as 'comment_author' 
    from comments inner join users on user_id = 'user_id' 
    where post_id='$get_id'";

Comment: you need to know what's the name of your `users` table and also the name of column with user_name. I assume that users table is `users` and also the name column is `name`

Comment: Yes.... the users table is "users" but the column for users is "user_name". Table "comments" has "comment_id", "post_id", "user_id", "comment", "date".

Comment: also which is `id` column in `users` table? Answer this question and I can help you to create final version of query

Comment: id column in users table is: "user_id" :)

Comment: I've changed sql query with new provided information

Comment: Thank you! That worked! You really helped me with this!  I appreciate that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. The `column_author` column simply does not exist in your `comments` table. You probably need to **join the comments table with the table that actually contains the data you need**.

Example:

```
SELECT A.*, B.`name` as comment_author FROM `comments` A
LEFT JOIN `users` B ON A.`user_id` = B.`id`
WHERE A.`post_id`='$get_id'
```

Remember to always properly escape your SQL queries.